# how to print select text in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code of html and javascript.
I want to print the table below, but I am unable to print.

Please give me some solution.

I should be able to print the following code except buttons, if possible.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <center>
            <a href="file:///C:/Users/genius/Desktop/shop-bill-app/items.html"id="login" onClick="confirm('Are You Sure?')">
              Logout
            </a>
        </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><center>Item Name</center></td>
        <td><center>Notebook</center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><center>Item No</center></td><td><center>1</center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><center>Category</center></td>
        <td><center>Notebooks & Books</center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <center>Quantity</center>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form>
            <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
            <input  value="submit" type="button" onclick="updateVal()" id="theButton"/>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><center>Price</center></td>
        <td><center>$2.50</center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><center>Tax</center></td>
        <td><center><div id="tax">Tax: 0</div></center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><center>Discount</center></td>
        <td><center><div id="discount">Discount: 0</div></center></td>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><center>Total</center></td>
        <td><center><div id="total">Total: 0</div></center></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <center>
          <a style="text-decoration:none" href="javascript:AlertIt();">
            <input  type="button" value="Buy">
          </a>
        </center>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
          <a style="text-decoration:none" href="file:///C:/Users/GENIUS/Desktop/shop-bill-app/notebook.html">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
          </a></center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>

    function updateVal() {
      var button = document.getElementById("theButton")
      var send= button.form.valueId.value ;
      var quantiy=send;
      var costPerItem=2.5;
      var amount= costPerItem*quantiy;
      var tax= (amount*1.5)/100;
      var discount=(amount*1)/100;
      var total= amount-discount+tax;
      document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "$" + tax;
      document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "$" + discount;
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$" + total;
    }

    updateVal();

    function AlertIt() {
      var answer = confirm ("Please click on OK to continue.")
      if (answer)
      window.location="file:///C:/Users/GENIUS/Desktop/shop-bill-app/notebook-
      receipt.html";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _unable to print_?

Comment: If you mean print as in print to paper, and you just don't want the buttons to show when printing, use CSS to hide them on print media.

Comment: Before downvote, try to explain yourself, after learning program, of course.

Answer (score -1):

You can put td item in

tag and then print using ('#idoftd').text() easily.

Answer (score -1):

```
it looks ok to me ... check it out on
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2bcLxqu2/